# Impala JDBC connection issue in spark cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hadoop-yarn, impala

Impala jdbc connection throwing below exception while running spark job in cluster mode. Spark job creates hive table and does impala table invalidate/refresh using JDBC.  The same job executes successfully in spark client mode.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: [Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500169) Unable to connect to server: GSS initiate failed. at om.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.impala.core.ImpalaJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  protected def getImpalaConnection(impalaJdbcDriver: String, impalaJdbcUrl: String): Connection = {
if (impalaJdbcDriver.length() == 0) return null
try {
  Class.forName(impalaJdbcDriver).newInstance
  UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser.doAs(
    new PrivilegedAction[Connection] {
      override def run(): Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(impalaJdbcUrl)
    }
  )
} catch {
  case e: Exception => {
    println(e.toString() + " --> " + e.getStackTraceString)
    throw e
  }
} }

val   impalaJdbcDriver = "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver"

val impalaJdbcUrl = "jdbc:impala://<Impala_Host>:21050/default;AuthMech=1;SSL=1;KrbRealm=HOST.COM;KrbHostFQDN=_HOST;KrbServiceName=impala;REQUEST_POOL=xyz"

println("Start impala connection")

val impalaConnection = getImpalaConnection(impalaJdbcDriver,impalaJdbcUrl)


val result = impalaConnection.createStatement.executeQuery(s"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM testTable")
println("End impala connection")
```

Build thick jar and use below given spark submit command. You can pass additional parameters like file,jars if needed.

Spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --keytab /home/testuser/testuser.keytab --principal testuser@host.COM  --queue xyz--class com.dim.UpdateImpala
```

Make changes like below as per your spark version

For Spark1: UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser

For Spark2 : UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer of your question with us ! Would you care explain why there were an error and what it is you are doing please ?

Comment: @eliasah: I was getting Impala JDBC connection issue from spark job in the cluster(Kerbores enabled) mode. Most of the forums recommended passing keytab and principal in spark-submit command but it didn't work in my case. To solve this, I made the change to JDBC connection code and it worked.

Comment: I didn't ask for me. I asked so it can be shared with the community. Thank you :)